# How to use ComponentObjectPropsOptions in Nuxt composition-api

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Are there any way to use ComponentObjectPropsOptions in nuxtjs/composition-api?

In Vue3, you can use ComponentObjectPropsOptions like below.

```
import { defineComponent, ComponentObjectPropsOptions } from "vue";
```

```
  props: {
    msg: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  } as ComponentObjectPropsOptions<CustomProps>,
```

However there is not ComponentObjectPropsOptions in '@nuxtjs/composition-api'.
Does anyone know how to use this in Nuxt?